# What is the purpose of Task Queue in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am working on project using GWT, Google app engine. I spent whole day for understanding task queue but i did not understand. could you please tell me what is the purpose of Task Queue. And now i am using automatic scaling so server side request processing limit is Only 1 minute so Using task queue shall i process my request more than 1 minute using Task Queue on server side? Any help??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In short, [task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) are for "work outside of a user request, initiated by a user request" making them good for "background work." Instead of the 1 minute limit for normal requests, Tasks can run for up to 10 minutes. That does mean that you might not have the results of the Task before a typical user request times out (or throws the DeadlineExceededError).